# Change temperature unit on Total Launcher

Tags: launcher, app-widgets, weather

I'm using Total Launcher, from the makers of ssLauncher. It has a weather widget that uses [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org). The default string is `%4.1f°` and the widget shows Celsius.

I tried every letter in the alphabet in place of the `f` but most of them said invalid format and none of them gave an expected value.

Is it possible to change the unit to Fahrenheit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Total Launcher **Options** screen, then select **Behavior**. Towards the bottom is a checkbox to **Use US customary units**.

Comment: Additional note: the `f` on the string is not for *Fahrenheit*, but for *decimal **floating point***. If you're interested in modifying the *format*, take a look at [Android (string) Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)